# fb:multi-friend-selector with stream.publish

Tags: php, facebook

How can I capture the friends selected in a fb:multi-friend-selector?

The only way I know how would use fb:request-form and result in initiating a facebook request - which is obviously not an option.

Populating the target ids in a stream.publish will be easy enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. However I found a [jquery plugin](http://mike.brevoort.com/2010/08/10/introducing-the-jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-plugin/) that looks exactly like multi-friend-selector which allows you to do such.